# Send data from TableView to DetailView Swift even if it not on UITableList

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Whenever a user types a name in the search bar and if that name is on my JSON and displayed in UITableView, I can click on that name and the string gets passed to my other view controller. But now, I also want to save and pass the searched name even if it not on my JSON. That way, a user could search whatever "medicine" name they want, and if that name is not on my JSON list, it still gets saved and passed to my other view controller.

Here is the code for my tableView:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class rxListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let rxlist = try! JSON(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "rxList01", ofType: "json")!)! as Data)
    var filteredRxList = [JSON]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        searchController.isActive = true
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering(){
            return filteredRxList.count
        }
        return rxlist.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rxCell", for: indexPath)

        var data: JSON

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            data = filteredRxList[indexPath.row]
            let countryName = data["term"].stringValue

            cell.textLabel?.text = countryName
        }else{
            data = rxlist[indexPath.row]
            tableView.reloadData()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func filteredContentForSearchText(searchText: String){
        filteredRxList = rxlist.array!.filter { country in
            return country["term"].stringValue.localizedLowercase.contains(searchText.localizedLowercase)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool{
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func isFiltering() -> Bool{
        return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "moreinfo"{
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
                let data: JSON
                if isFiltering(){
                    data = filteredRxList[indexPath.row]
                }else{
                    data = rxlist[indexPath.row]
                }
                let controller = segue.destination as? medDetailsViewController
                let final = data["term"].stringValue
                controller?.name = final
                controller?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller?.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    } 
}

extension rxListPetsTablViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating{
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredContentForSearchText(searchText: searchController.searchBar.text!)
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the viewController:

```
import UIKit

class medDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    var name = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lbl.text = "\(name) "
    }
```

Is there way to implement that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your next view controller, create an optional String variable and pass the value "searchController.searchBar.text!". For example, in your prepare method, add below code:

```
let controller = segue.destination as? medDetailsViewController
controller.searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
```